# How to add a UIView into navigationItem.backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to achieve this [image: just like Whats App]

this is my code

```
    let contactName=UILabel()
    contactName.text=chat?.Name
    contactName.font=UIFont(name: "System", size: 17)
    contactName.sizeToFit()
    let contactImg=UIImageView()
    contactImg.image=UIImage(named: (chat?.Image)!)
    contactImg.frame.size.width=20
    contactImg.frame.size.height=20
    contactImg.layer.cornerRadius=contactImg.frame.height/2
    let backButtonView=UIView()
    backButtonView.addSubview(contactImg)
    backButtonView.addSubview(contactName)
    backButtonView.frame.size.width=20+contactName.frame.width
    backButtonView.frame.size.height=max(contactImg.frame.height,contactName.frame.height)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButtonView)
```

but when I run app it shows the default backbarbutton
[image]

what am I doing wrong here please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let profileImage = UIImage(named: "profile_image")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = profileImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = profileImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Jhon"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I want to keep the default backindicatorimage just like we see in WhatsApp. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

Aditya is right, but here's a little more explanation. From the Apple docs:

> When configuring your bar button item, do not assign a custom view to it; the navigation item ignores custom views in the back bar button anyway.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem

Also, the UIBarButtonItem is "...specialized for placement on a toolbar or tab bar. You typically use Interface Builder to create and configure bar button items."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem